# how to select a distinct of two specific columns in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2014

select distinct (pc.id,pc.PolicyPremiumID) ,pc.policyPremiumCatID,b.nin, b.firstname+' '+coalesce((b.middleInitial),'')+' '+b.lastname as fullname, b.gender,ppc.amount from
bio_data  b, medicalInsurance m, policy p, policyPremium pp,premiumCategories pc,policyPremiumCategory ppc
where b.nin=m.patientBin and m.policyID=p.id and (p.id=pp.policyID and pp.policyID=p.id) and pp.id=pc.policyPremiumID and pc.policyPremiumcatID=ppc.id
and p.id=82

in the above query, I want to have a distinct of those two columns
it is duplicating instead of 7 return values it bring 14
Can some please help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method:

**Sample select query which list all values:**

```
mysql> select * from new_table;
+---------+------------+
| premium | sumassured |
+---------+------------+
|    1000 |     100000 |
|    2000 |     200000 |
|    3000 |     300000 |
|    1000 |     100000 |
|    1000 |     100000 |
|    3000 |     300000 |
|    4000 |     400000 |
+---------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Select Query which lists Distinct Value from multiple Tables:**

```
mysql> select distinct premium,sumassured from new_table;
+---------+------------+
| premium | sumassured |
+---------+------------+
|    1000 |     100000 |
|    2000 |     200000 |
|    3000 |     300000 |
|    4000 |     400000 |
+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can use the same for N number of Rows.

Comment: thank murali!! but I want a situation where only the two will be considered where having other selection
for example


select distinct (premium,sumassured), something, something from new_table;

the uniqueness of only this  (premium,sumassured)

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you mean, You need only two values or what, Give some clear explanation I will give you a Fix.

Comment: sorry for that!!!

ok!! I want only the premium column in the new_table to bring distinct values while other selection can bring any value

for example

select (distinct premium), sumassured  from new_table this way

only the premium will be affected by the distinct clause.
thanks for the patient!!